# Check whether generic SObject is updateable

Tags: security, dml, fls

How do I check whether a generic SObject is updateable before DML operation. For standard and custom objects I know the general pattern is:

```
Schema.sObjectType.Account.isUpdateable()
```

However if I have an object record defined as:

```
SObject obj;
```

How would I go about checking whether this generic SObject isUpdateable() before an update operation. I currently have:

```
obj.getSObjectType().getDescribe().isUpdateable()
```

But PMD is still giving an error.

Comment: Note that PMD can't fully understand your code. Your approach looks good to me (with a null check); I'd use [Suppressing warnings](https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html) and move on.